# Hyphenating compound words

Tags: punctuation, hyphens

Is there a rule whether a compound word is hyphenated (at a line break) between its components?

`potash` is hyphenated as `pot-ash`, but `potassium` is hyphenated as `po-tas-si-um`. 
From [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/potassium):

> Origin of POTASSIUM 
>   New Latin, from potassa potash, from English potash

Why is potassium not hyphenated `pot-as-si-um`, which would preserve the sense?

Is there some general rule about this?

Comment: The two "o"s are not even pronounced the same. What leads you to believe they should be hyphenated the same?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typesetting

Comment: @FumbleFingers How is typesetting English off-topic? Hyphenation rules have a linguistic basis.

Comment: I think *potassa* is treated as opaque, even if it did come from *pot-ash*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from breaking at double letters, hyphenation generally follows syllable boundaries. **Potash** is pronounced as the two words *pot ash*, but **potassium** is pronounced *po-TASS-ee-um*.

As a more specific rule, compound words, which until recently were often written hyphenated even in the middle of a line (mail-box, pot-ash), have a (preferred) hyphenation point between the base words.

Comment: The *maximal onset principle* tells us that /s/ belongs to /sɪ/, though you could argue that it's *ambisyllabic* (belongs to /ˈtæs/ as well).

Comment: @snailboat As a general rule I'd agree, but at least in American pronunciation, the Latin *-ium* suffix is such a chunk unto itself that a speaker speaking by syllable will almost always pronounce *-ee-um* as a standalone pair, attaching any consonant phonemes to the preceding syllable.

Comment: Do I understand this right? 1. A word, which is recognized as and pronounced as a composition of two words, is hyphenated between the words, but a word, which is no longer recognized as composition and pronounced as if it was just one single word, is hyphenated according to the usual rules without respect to its constituent parts. 2. "potassium" falls into the second category.

Comment: @Stephen In my experience, yes, (1) is true. I know with certainty that (2) is false; it is [a neo-Latin word made up in 1808](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium#History).